# Generate diff with prefix

Tags: diff

I have a file which is not under git control and I need to generate a patch for it. I know I can use `diff -Naur file file_new > diff.patch` but it will produce something like:

```
--- file    <timestamp>
+++ file_new    <timestamp>
<diff content>
```

But I want to get something like git diff does:

```
--- a/file <timestamp>
+++ b/file <timestamp>
<diff content>
```

Is there a way to generate this type of patch without using git diff and editing it manually?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I created a simple function in my ~/.zshrc file that does it. Hope this would be helpful for someone.

```
diffgit () {
        local dir_a=a/${$(dirname $1)#pwd}
        local dir_b=b/${$(dirname $1)#pwd}
        mkdir -p ./${dir_a} ./${dir_b}
        cp $1 ./${dir_a}
        cp $2 ./${dir_b}/$(basename $1)
        diff -Naur ${dir_a} ${dir_b}
        rm -rf ./{a,b}
}
```